# Symfony private service performance increase

Tags: symfony

Turning public Symofony services into private increases performance.

> Private services are special because they allow the container to optimize whether and how they are instantiated. This increases the container's performance. - [How to Create Service Aliases and Mark Services as Private](https://symfony.com/doc/master/service_container/alias_private.html)

How much does it increase performance?

Answer (score 3):

Performance gain will vary on different applications. The best way to find out is to convert your app and create benchmarks for comparison. However, when deciding between public and private services you should consider not only performance but also best practices. This should be faster because the container gets optimized by removing unused services.